# Why do I have question marks instead of ordinary icons?

Tags: unity

Some applications produce question marks for their subwindows in the unity menu instead of ordinary icons. What could cause this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a program installed manually, that's all I can tell based in your current amount of details.

Comment: @xangua No, it's the xeoma application. I installed it over the Ubuntu Software-Center. It shows the main icon, but the camerawindow appears with a question mark.

Comment: It's a bug in the application then, most likely.

Comment: @dobey I see, but I also get this question marks in Tumblr or Gmail-Apps Ubuntu wants me to install if I use firefox.